# Blending in the navbar if div reaches certain position

Tags: jquery, css

For my Website i made a nice "Jumbotron".

To show it better i want to set to opacity of my navbar to 0 until the user reaches the next layer. Then it should blend in.

So i wrote this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).on('scroll', function() {


        var scrollTop     = $(window).scrollTop(),
            thirdLayerOffset = $('#thirdLayer').offset().top,
            distanceTop      = (thirdLayerOffset - scrollTop);

        if(distanceTop < 0) {
            $('#navMenu').css({
                opacity: 1
            })
        }

        else if (distanceTop > 0) {
            $('#navMenu').css({
                'opacity': 0
            })
        }



    });


});
```

Works fine so far but i want the whole experience smoother. So i tried the jquery .animate() .

```
if(distanceTop < 0) {
    $('#navMenu').animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 500, function() {
    });
}
```

Using this causes a problem: When i scroll up fast again it stays and starts to blink like crazy.
Im pretty sure it has a problem with the 500ms.

But I dont have an idea how to fix it.

I have seen other websites using something like this so it should be possible. 
Can anybody give me a hint on how to make it work?

Greetings

Edit: added HTML:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navMenu" id="navMenu">
            <div class="container col-md-12" style="background-color: #ffffff">
                <div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="lib/img/logo.jpg" id="logo">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <!-- Space for menu Bar-->
                </div>

            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>


    <div class="container-fluid">

<!-- JumboTronText1 -->
        <div class="col-md-12 JumboC">


     <div class="getInvisible2">
                <h1 class="animated infinite pulse" id="pulseHeader">Durchatmen und runterscrollen<br> <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down"></i>
                </h1>
            </div>


                <!-- JumboTron Image with second Text-->


                   <div class="JumboCImage" id="JumboCImage">
                       <h2 style="z-index: -1;" id="JumboCImageText">Wilkommen.
                       </h2>
                   </div>


            <div class="container-fluid secondPart">
                <div class="secondLayer" id="secondLayer">



                </div>
                <!-- Third Layer Blend Menu in-->
                <div class="thirdLayer col-md-12 container-fluid" id="thirdLayer">

                    <h1>
    <br>TEXT<br>

                    </h1>


                </div>
```

Sorry for the bad formatting. Something went wrong. I'll try to fix it after work.

Comment: A minimal example which also contains HTML and CSS would be helpful. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with css3 transitions (depending on your browser compatability requirements).

Add transitions and a faded class to the nav menu styles:

```
#navMenu {
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}     

#navMenu.faded{
    opacity:0;
}
```

When you reach your target scroll positions, add or remove the .faded class as as necessary with addClass or removeClass functions.

```
if(distanceTop < 0) {
    $('#navMenu').addClass('faded')
}
```

Comment: Of course! My brain just went blank on the subject i guess. Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you mark it as correct if this is what you go with? Trying to level up over here! Thanks, dude!

Comment: I will, just to be fair i wanted to try it out before. As soon as i have i will !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of animating with jQuery you could try adding a transition to the `#navmenu` in your css

eg

```
#navmenu{
transition: opacity 0.5s;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s; }
```

Comment: Than you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vx7d5h6L/1/)

i think that's what you are looking for

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        var scrollTop     = $(window).scrollTop(),
            thirdLayerOffset = $('#thirdLayer').offset().top,
            distanceTop      = (thirdLayerOffset - scrollTop);
        if(distanceTop > 0) {
            if(distanceTop < 200 && distanceTop >= 100)
                $('#navMenu').css({ opacity: (distanceTop-100)/100});
            else if(distanceTop <100)
                $('#navMenu').css({ opacity: 0});
            else 
                $('#navMenu').css({ opacity: 1});
        }
        else if (distanceTop <= 0) {
            $('#navMenu').css({
                'opacity': 0
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because upon each scrolling that you perform, the `scroll` event is triggered which in turn causes the animations to get queued.

In order to stop *immediately* queuing of the `animate` method, you can check whether the element is currently being *animated*. And if so, prevent it by returning `false`.

```
if(distanceTop < 0) {
    if($('#navMenu').is(':animated')){
        return false;
    }
    $('#navMenu').animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 500, function() {
  });
}
```

*Note the usage of jQuery's [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method.*